# WCF SOAP receive empty list

Tags: c#, android, wcf, soap, ksoap2

I have an Android application and an WCF Service to store data. I try to send a request to the service, with the Android application (using kSOAP2).
All works fine, but.. When I tried to send list (simple string or integer list) to the service, the WCF service recept the message but the list is always empty !

My SOAP message is like that :

```
<MyList>
    <int>12</int>
    <int>50</int>
</MyList>
```

No error in client or service... But the list is always empty and I have no idea why.
Someone know the correct format for WCF list ?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit :**

My interface in service :

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = MyService.NamespaceV3)]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void MarkMessagesAsRead(List<int> ids, DateTime readDate, int employeeId);
}
```

Parameters readDate and employeeId works properly, but the list ids is always empty (not null but empty).

**Edit 2 :**

My complete request is :

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <v:Header />
    <v:Body>
        <MarkMessagesAsRead xmlns="http://schemas.xxx.fr/Mobile">
            <ids><int>10293</int><int>10295</int></ids>
            <readDate i:type="d:DateTime">2015-10-19T16:32:44.04</readDate>
            <employeeId i:type="d:int">18572</employeeId>
        </MarkMessagesAsRead>
    </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

Comment: Post your interface and wcf service. It looks like a serialization/deserialization problem. In your interface, your list is typed as List<someType> ?

Comment: Yes is typed as List<int>. I have updated my post to add the interface. Thanks.

Comment: I created a service with same interface, and the xml that worked looks like:
<MarkMessagesAsRead>
 <ids>
    <int>2</int>
    <int>3</int>
    <int>4</int>
 </ids>
 <readDate>2015-10-23T13:00:00</readDate>
 <employeeId>0</employeeId>
</MarkMessagesAsRead>

Comment: Thans for your help @RicardoPontual . I have edited my post to add my request. The difference with your request, is the "i:type" for two last parameters. Maybe is a problem with the namespace or a missing type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution: I simply add the correct namespace to the "int" element in the list.

The namespace to use for arrays and list is : http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays